# Параметр функции, содержащий одно из нескольких значений

Tags: c++, c

Каким образом можно описать параметр функции?

Допустим есть функция: `void stick(int a, inb &b, /* ? */ direct)`

Собственно вместе с этим `direct` я передаю один из двух параметров - `right` и `left`. И в теле функции должна происходить проверка, на указанный параметр.

Comment: А почему бы не `enum`?

Comment: @VladD оформите в виде ответа, использовал enum только один раз и очень давно, даже не помню зачем он, сейчас читаю, это то что необходимо

Comment: @ParanoidPanda  Лично я ничего не понял. Что такое direct? Почему именно идентификатор третьего параметра не указан, а указаны только идентификаторы первых двух? Какая проверка на какой параметр должна происходить?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow просто я давно хотел спросить как можно описать свою функцию не только через переменные но и сделать параметры. direct - направление. например у нас есть функция Travel(direct) - и там проверка куда идти. Собственно все.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
enum Direction
{
    Left,
    Right
};

void stick(int a, inb &b, Direction d);
{
    switch (d)
    {
    case Left:
        break;
    case Right:
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

Заметьте, что `enum` в версиях C++ до C++11 даёт достаточно слабую типизацию. Например, такой код компилируется:

```
enum Direction
{
    Left,
    Right
};

enum Direction2
{
    North = 5,
    South = 7
};

void f(Direction d)
{
    switch (d)
    {
    case North:
        break;
    case South:
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Для компилятора все `enum`'ы — просто числовые константы.

Но начиная с C++11, лучше использовать строго типизированный `enum`:

```
enum class Direction
{  //^^^^^
    Left,
    Right
};

enum WrongDirection
{
    Left = 1,
    Right = 0
};

void f(Direction d)
{
    switch (d)
    {
    case Direction::Left: // а не WrongDirection::Left
        break;
    case Direction::Right:
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Здесь компилятор не даст вам случайно использовать неправильный тип.